# Why can I compile this code without error, even if I pass an invalid type argument?

Tags: c++

"func" takes constant reference of class C as its argument.
But I mistakenly passed string to it.

I expected that an error like "no matching function..." "no known conversion from..." would be obtained, but compilation is complete without any errors, and program get segmentation fault.

Why is the compiler not causing an error even if the argument of the function is incorrect?

Version of compiler
clang++ 3.9.1
g++ 6.3.1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class C ;

void func( const C &_c )
{}

class C
{
public :
    C( const std::string &_s )
    {
        func( _s ) ;
    }
} ;

int main()
{
    C c( "foo" ) ;
}
```

Comment: If it's invalid it's invalid. What do you want the compiler to do? Pretend it's valid? You're passing a `std::string` to something that's demanding a `C`. Are you looking for a template function?

Answer (score 4):

Since you have a constructor that can make a `C` from an `std::string`, it essentially compiled your `func( _s )` as if it were `func( C( _s ) )`. It's obvious to us that this will just result in infinite recursion and crash your program (since that function is the function you're in now), but technically it's not invalid C++, so the compiler allowed it. If you didn't want this to work, you could declare your constructor `explicit`, which means that the compiler will never use it unless you explicitly call it.